# Архитектурные решения для нескольких нод

Tags: java, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Вопрос возник входе спора о правильном решении в рамках ООП.

Допустим есть журнал каких-то документов. И в приложении очень частая операция - запрос количества документов. Причем нужно именно точное значение.

1. В простом случае создаем сущность журнала, и все операции вставки/удаления новых записей прогоняем только через эту сущность. Соответственно, сущность журнала знает о том, изменились ли данные с какого-то момента. И если идут повторные запросы на количество записей в журнале, то можно возвращать старое значение, не обращаясь к хранилищу (допустим, хранилищем может быть реляционная БД). Наша задача - минимизировать запросы к хранилищу данных, считая такие запросы медленными.
2. Но что делать если существует пул сущностей журнала? Или даже приложение развернуто на нескольких нодах - и таких сущностей несколько? 
   Т.е. каждый экземпляр сущности журнала документов представляет собой один и тот же журнал. Соответственно, теперь каждый экземпляр журнала уже точно не может сказать добавлялись или нет новые записи в журнал без обращения к хранилищу. Понятно что в самом хранилище данных тоже можно это "ловить" и возвращать старое значения если кол-во записей не менялось. Но как вообще избежать операций доступа к хранилищу при запросе количества записей? Интересует правильное решение в рамках ООП.

Есть конечно, вариант мультитона - т.е. разбить сущность журнала, например по первым буквам названия документов/ номерам и т.д. на несколько сущностей, каждая из которых представляет собой лишь часть журнала.
Но как-то это тоже не всегда удобно.

Comment: Никак, если у вас изменения системы идут через несколько точек, вы не можете быть уверены в состоянии системы до того момента, пока явно ее об этом не спросите.

Comment: а если создать что-то типа диспетчера или один из объектов назначить главным? и его всегда уведомлять при добавлении/удалении? соответственно количество запрашивать только у него?

Comment: И каким образом разные ноды будут знать куда посылать запрос и что отвечать на не принадлежащий им запрос? Проще все-таки у хранилища спрашивать.